# Display another key's value if one value is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a request to a website for a game; the game is League of Legens if any of you are familiar with it but it doesn't matter.

I want to pull some data to get the name of a champion, the thing is that Riot (The API's provider) gives an endpoint to get some points of each champion and the ID so I have to make a request to another website to get the name of the champion but since that second website doesn't have the data that I am looking for (which are the points). I can't use just that data.

Anyway, the problem that I am facing is that I already have the Id's from the champs that are shown on the person's profile, which are 3. With the second request I want to compare the id of all champs and if it find the same id of the 3 champs requested before it displays the name of only those 3 champs. I'm using the `request` package to do this on `Node`; this is what I have, whenever I make the request it displays only one name: the last one.

```
request.get(`https://lan.api.pvp.net/championmastery/location/LA1/player/24244/topchampions?api_key=${API}`, (error, response, body) => {
  let parsedInfo = JSON.parse(body)

  var data = {
    "id": [],
    "points": []
  }

  for(x in parsedInfo) {
    data.id.push(parsedInfo[x].championId)
    data.points.push(parsedInfo[x].championPoints)

    var checkChampId = parsedInfo[x].championId
  }

  request.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json', (error, response, body) => {
    let champParse = JSON.parse(body)

    for(x in champParse.data) {
      if(checkChampId == champParse.data[x].key) {
        console.log(champParse.data[x].name)
      }
    }
  })
```

Let me know if I need to explain my issue more in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only saving the id of the last champ

```
var checkChampId = parsedInfo[x].championId
```

First you need to save all ids, you can create an array to store it

```
var champIds = [];
for(x in parsedInfo) {
  data.id.push(parsedInfo[x].championId)
  data.points.push(parsedInfo[x].championPoints)

  // saves the id in the array
  champIds.push(parsedInfo[x].championId);
}
```

Now with all ids you can check in the other loop if the key is present in the array:

```
for(x in champParse.data) {
  // check if the key is in the array of ids you saved
  if (champIds.indexOf(Number(champParse.data[x].key)) !== -1) {
    console.log(champParse.data[x].name)
  }
}
```

If the types are different you can search with another method

```
champIds.filter(function (id) { return id == champParse.data[x].key; }).length > 0
```

This is going to compare without considering the object type and if it finds anything that matches it will be true.

Comment: Hello I tried this and it wasn't working; the thing is that the `key` key from the second request is a string and the Ids from the first request are integers; I think that it is causing it not to work; any idea on hwo to solve this? Can I parse the ids or something like that?

Comment: You can convert `key` to a number with `Number(champParse.data[x].key)`. (I updated the answer)

Comment: or with parseInt()

Comment: Ah, it's working now; I knew about Number and parseInt, I just was confused on where to use it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the first for loop create an array and append your parsedInfo

```
for(var x = 0; x < in parsedInfo.length; x ++) {
    data.id.push(parsedInfo[x].championId)
    data.points.push(parsedInfo[x].championPoints)

    var checkChampId = []

    checkChampId.push(parsedInfo[x].championId)
```

also try this in second loop

```
for(var x = 0; x <  champParse.data; x ++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are assigning the variable

`var checkChampId = parsedInfo[x].championId`  inside of the encapsulated scope  of the first `for loop` which causes it to be deleted after each cycle.

Define  `checkChampId`  globally and use it as an array of `ids`  rather than a single value. or move your request code within the same scope as the definition of the `checkChampId  var`

```js
for (x in parsedInfo) {
  data.id.push(parsedInfo[x].championId)
  data.points.push(parsedInfo[x].championPoints)

  var checkChampId = parsedInfo[x].championId

  /* removed the }  here */

  request.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json', (error, response, body) => {
        let champParse = JSON.parse(body)

        for (x in champParse.data) {
          if (checkChampId == champParse.data[x].key) {
            console.log(champParse.data[x].name)
          }
        }

      } /* add the } here */
```